# SharePoint questions

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

We have https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ (currently nearly 60,000 questions compared to less than 300 here).

Should we edit the various [sharepoint](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint) tags to suggest asking on sharepoint.stackexchange.com?

Something like:

> Most SharePoint questions would be better suited to sharepoint.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @fixer1234 Agreed, but on [SU] there are are < 300 questions tagged with some variant of Sharepoint compared with 60,000 on the sharepoint stack. So presumably many more eyeballs over there.

Comment: @fixer1234 That's what I was suggesting. I was hoping a sharepoint expert would wander by to comment ;)

Comment: I wondered where I got that idea from.  It sounded vaguely familiar.  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took a moment to browse through a handful of the tagged questions here, and have some observations.

- Of the few questions I looked at, most did not relate strongly enough to SharePoint to indicate that they would be **strictly better off** on SP.SE, although the [most recent one](https://superuser.com/q/1043970/431072), as of this writing, certainly does.
- Some, like [Sharepoint Sites on SP 2010](https://superuser.com/q/1008818/431072), are directly SharePoint-related, and therefore would be fine to ask on SP.SE, but aren't necessarily *not in scope* for SU - I believe there is a range of questions for which the scopes overlap. In such cases, I'd suggest directing them to SP.SE only if they fail to generate any/enough useful answers here.
- SP.SE still has the [lowest vote-to-post ratio in the network](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1094/35499) (possibly excepting any sites created after that post was written and therefore not included in the provided query). A side effect of this fact is that it can be very difficult for a new user to gain rep there, which may discourage users from posting more questions there after earning tumbleweed two or three times. SU has awarded close to 3 times as many Tumbleweed badges as it has Nice Answer badges; on SP.SE that ratio is closer to **200 to 1.**
- A significant portion of SP.SE's questions are of a highly technical nature, involving aspects such as PowerShell scripting and server farm administration. I'm a Site Collection Administrator for a team site in a large corporate environment, and while I have access to do *almost* anything I want/need to do on that site, I have often found a question on SP.SE that exactly matches my situation, except that the OP had access to PowerShell and/or Central Administration in their environment and thus accepted an answer involving one or both of those utilities, neither of which are within my purview. While, before today, I had not considered asking SP-related questions here on SU, I am now contemplating whether I might actually be more likely to receive answers written for the user with the privileges I *do* have at my disposal by asking them here, instead.
- Thus, I would definitely not recommend updating the tag wiki with the proposed phrase as written - "Most Sharepoint questions would be better suited to sharepoint.stackexchange.com". However, I think that something more along the lines of "If your question is *directly* focused on SharePoint, *consider* asking it on sharepoint.stackexchange.com" might be appropriate.

All this being said, I'm hardly a top user on SP.SE, so take this with a grain of salt.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to make detailed observations and comments :)